# Angular service holds data and proceeds http request within itself

Tags: angular, typescript, httpclient

I'm planning to use the services in angular to proceed http request by themself rather than returning an observable to the requesting components and managing the data.
So that when a component requests data, it gets the data directly from the service that holds them.

So if the data are already loaded and still up to date (loaded within the last minute) they are directly returned to the requesting component.
If not, the data will get loaded and saved within the service before returning to the component.
The official tutorial of Angular shows that the service returns an observable which will get subscribed by the component and the component has to manage the data..

Does this make sense?

Because I've got the case that several components need the same data and therefore it does not make sense to load them several time. Also for this first prototype that I am working on, I am trying to avoid Redux and something like that..

What do you think? Could anyone provide an example service that proceeds the http request within itself and manages the data?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The "typical aproach" is use a "caché" in service using shareReply. Some like this [link](https://medium.com/@AurelienLeloup/cache-http-requests-with-rxjs-for-angular-eb9bee93824d)

Answer (score 0):

Behavior subjects are your way to go. They memoize your data and you can refresh them.

```js
data = new BehaviorSubject<any>(null);

fetchData() {
  this.http.get(...).subscribe(res => this.data.next(res));
}

// In your component

this.service.data.asObservable().subscribe(console.log);
```

Although this is as simple as that, may I suggest you take a look into [Akita JS](https://datorama.github.io/akita/), which is a library doing that for you, which is way more easier to use than something like Redux, and have not really any much complexity into it either